# laravel eloquent using if statement then use eloquent having method return - SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column

Tags: php, laravel, database, eloquent

i want to use laravel eloquent having method when i get some data.

table i use

```
po_trading_details
- po_trading_id
- item_id
- price_id
- price
- qty
- description
- type [Liter, Kilo Liter]
- created_at 
- updated_at
- deleted_at

so_trading
- customer_id
- date
- code 
- sub_total
- tax_id
- total
- created_at 
- updated at
- deleted_at

so_tradind_detail
- so_trading_id
- item_id
- price_id
- qty
- type [Liter, Kilo Liter]
- created_at 
- updated at
- deleted_at
```

i want get data with an condition like this

> if po_trading_details.type = "Kilo Liter", "qty" * 1000, "qty" * 1)

the i use this command in my cli and is work properly

```
select *, IF (`type` = "Kilo Liter", `qty` * 1000, `qty` * 1) as final_qty from po_trading_details having final_qty < 1000;
```

but when i use my eloquent this return an error

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'final_qty' in 'having clause' (SQL: select * from `po_trading_details` having `final_qty` > 123)

and this is the code:

```
...
        $so = SoTrading::findOrFail($id);

        $model = new PoTradingDetail();
        $new_model = $model->query(DB::raw('IF (`type` = "Kilo Liter", `qty` * 1000, `qty` * 1) as final_qty'));
        
        foreach ($so->so_trading_details as $so_trading_detail) {
            $new_model->having('final_qty', '>', $so_trading_detail->qty);
        }

        $model = $new_model->get();

        return $this->ResponseJsonData($model);
...
```

anyone can solve this problem

Comment: In your having clause you are referring to `qty` while you select the clause as `final_qty` is that a typo?

Comment: no i already fix that, but return same error

Answer (score 0):

problem solved

instead using query use select method from eloquent

```
$new_model = $model->select(["*", DB::raw('IF (`type` = "KL", `qty` * 1000, `qty` * 1) as final_qty')]);
```

its happen because when i use the last query, my if statement not load in that query